# substring is subtracting things that it should not be. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When ever I hit the button that it is linked to it subtracts every letter but the minus symbol. Is there something wrong with the code below.

```
$(".Button:eq(2)").click(function(){
    if ($("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val().substring($("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val().length-1) == "+"))) {
    $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val().substring(0, $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val().length-1)));
    }
    $("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + "-");
});
```

The code is supposed to see if the last operator in the input field's value is a multiply, divide, add, and minus symbol. If one of those are there, replace it with the minus symbol, but if none are then, it adds a minus symbol.

Comment: What is `$("#Num_View").val()` when you enter this function?

Comment: @p.s.w.g It is a input text field

Comment: If it doesn't do what you expect then it is likely related to there being something wrong with the code. What should it be doing?

Comment: I know `#Num_View` is an input field. What's returned from `.val()`? Your code is very confusing and difficult to read. Probably if you just refactor this code to call `.val()` once, to place it in a temp variable, modify it, then call it `.val(...)` again to store back in the field, you'll find the issue.

Comment: @Chris If the + symbol is the last letter then it will remove it from the end and then add the minus symbol after it removes it.

Comment: please do not repeat yourself!   Your function should have at most one call to `val()` to  _read_ the element's value, and optionally another to write it.  jQuery also provides a "read-modify-write" version of `.val()`.

Comment: oh, and please describe what the code was _supposed_ to do, not just what it does!

Comment: What do you expect `newVar.val(newVar.val().length-1)` to do? As I see it that is setting the value of `newVar` to be `newVar.val().length-1` which doesn't look right at all...

Comment: OK guys the code is supposed to see if the last operator in the input fields value is a + symbol. If it is a plus symbol then it will remove it from the input text field's value and replace it with the - symbol.

Comment: @CDW so the `-` is _only_ added if the `+` was present?

Comment: @Alnitak Ok I want it to first check if any symbol is before it multiply,divide,add, and minus. If one of those are there it replaces it with the minus symbol. But if none are then it gos ahead and adds a minus symbol

Comment: FWIW I Think your original problem was what I indicated above that you are calling val far too many times and often in times when you are just wanting to read the value you are passing a value which will then not do what you want. Others have answered with ways to do it but if you want to debug what you have then you just need to break it down to separate clauses to see what each thing is doing and you'll quickly find where the calculations go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just remove an optional trailing `+` and append a trailing `-` then you could do:

```
var nv = $("#Num_View");
$(".Button:eq(2)").on( 'click', function(){
    nv.val( nv.val().replace( /\+?$/, '-' ) );
});
```

or

```
var nv = $("#Num_View");
$(".Button:eq(2)").on( 'click', function(){
    nv.val( function(index,value){ return value.replace( /\+?$/, '-' ) } );
});
```

**Edit**

> I want it to first check if any symbol is before it multiply,divide,add, and minus. If one of those are there it replaces it with the minus symbol. But if none are then it gos ahead and adds a minus symbol

Like this:

```
var nv = $("#Num_View");
$(".Button:eq(2)").on( 'click', function(){
    nv.val( nv.val().replace( /[*/+-]?$/, '-' ) );
});
```

or

```
var nv = $("#Num_View");
$(".Button:eq(2)").on( 'click', function(){
    nv.val( function(index,value){ return value.replace( /[*/+-]?$/, '-' ) } );
});
```

Comment: please don't forget the read/modify/write version of `.val()` that takes a function as its parameter...

Comment: @CDW No problem. Please accept whichever answer has helped so the question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to remove a trailing `+` (if present) and replace it with a `-`.

If so, replace the body of your callback with this:

```
$('#Num_View').val(function(_, t) {
    return t.replace(/\+$/, '-');
});
```

NB: `$(el).on('click', f)` is preferred over `$(el).click(f)` these days.  If you consistently use `.on` to register event handlers it avoids confusion that can arise because `.click` is used to both register a click handler and to trigger click events.

Comment: You forgot the `?` in the regular expression to make the `+` optional.

Comment: @MT0 the OP's comment appears to say that the `-` is only added if the `+` was removed, so I removed the `?` from the regexp.  Will revert it if the OP clarifies.